# Session variable does not persist

Tags: php, variables, session-variables

I can't seem to get my session variable to output. It works fine on the other one I'm using:

```
    $_SESSION['status']['register']['username'] = $username;
    header('Location: register-form.php');
```

When you are taken to `register-form.php` it should output the variable for you:

```
<?php
      if(isset($_SESSION['status']['register']['username'])){
      $username = $_SESSION['status']['register']['username'];
      } else {
      $username = '';
      }
?>
```

Exact same code is used on `email_address` and works fine.

**Here is the same code for the email**

```
$_SESSION['status']['register']['email_address'] = $email_address;
```

And on the form page:

```
<?php
     if(isset($_SESSION['status']['register']['email_address'])){
     $ea_value = $_SESSION['status']['register']['email_address'];
     } else {
     $ea_value = '';
     }
?>
```

Comment: Have you used session_start? http://uk1.php.net/function.session-start

Comment: @JakeN session_start is there, yes.

Comment: *"Exact same code is used on email_address and works fine"* --- *So*, show us. Don't leave out the *good stuff* ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- added code to OP. It's exactly the same.

Comment: Does the redirect work properly? What are the symptoms?

Comment: @JakubFedyczak redirect works fine, but the username variable does not persist. Email variable does, and they both use the same code. When you are redirected the input for `username` is blank and does not retain what you previously had in there. But `email_address` input does retain what was previously put in.

Comment: @Francesca Can you try adding echo($username); to be sure it's not a typo while passing it to form?

Comment: Results using `var_dump($_SESSION);` are the same for both pages I setup: `array(1) { ["status"]=> array(1) { ["register"]=> array(2) { ["email_address"]=> string(17) "email@example.com" ["username"]=> string(8) "USERNAME" } } }`

Comment: Hi @Fred-ii- session variable is being passed OK as I did `printr` and it is sending `username` with POST but is not outputting it. That's the issue here I think.

Answer (score -1):

You miss to initialize your session with

```
session_start();
```

at top of your register_form.php

Comment: The session_start is there. Please see comments.

Comment: Sorry, i didn't refresh this page, and not see your comments and the another smae answer.